# Javascript events in Firefox and IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox

I attach in my ASP.NET app to a cell `oncontextmenu`
a function `string.Format("OnCellContextMenu({0}, '{1}', true, true)", e.VisibleIndex, e.DataColumn.FieldName)`.

In my JS i define the following function.

```
function OnCellContextMenu(visibleIndex, fieldName, hasNote, hasValue) {
    currentVisibleIndex = visibleIndex;
    currentFieldName = fieldName;

    if (fieldName == "Name" || fieldName == "TOTAL") {
        EnableMenuItem('AddNote', false);
        EnableMenuItem('EditNote', false);
        EnableMenuItem('RemoveNote', false);
    }
    else {
        EnableMenuItem('AddNote', !hasNote && hasValue);
        EnableMenuItem('EditNote', hasNote);
        EnableMenuItem('RemoveNote', hasNote);
    }

    window.event.returnValue = false;

    gvPrevisions.SetFocusedRowIndex(visibleIndex);
    GridMenu.ShowAtPos(ASPxClientUtils.GetEventX(event), ASPxClientUtils.GetEventY(event));
}
```

Now, on IE works properlly, but on Firefox `window.event.returnValue = false;`
it is not executed. I googled around to see how the Firefox treats this return value and I got that I should call `e.preventDefault();` insdead of window.event. The problem is that in my function `e` is undefined.

Can you please help me finding a solution that works both on FF and IE?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Prevent the browsers menu on right click and showing my own.

Comment: use this. if(window.event.preventDefault) { window.event.preventDefault(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way out.

I declared a function in this way:

```
function OnCellContextMenu(e, visibleIndex, fieldName, hasNote, hasValue)
```

and the association in this way:

```
e.Cell.Attributes.Add("oncontextmenu", string.Format("OnCellContextMenu(event, {0}, '{1}', true, true)", e.VisibleIndex, e.DataColumn.FieldName));
```

then in the function I got `var currentEvent = (window.event) ? window.event : e;`
and used `currentEvent` across other function calls like `ASPxClientUtils.PreventEventAndBubble(currentEvent);`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code to use jQuery, which works across all browsers E.g:

```
$('body').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    //Stop browser from opening context menu
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do more stuff
});
```

Comment: It will be nice but I'm using the Devxpress GridView and I'm setting oncontextmenu attribute to a grid cell in a particular way. Inside grids HtmlDataCellPrepared server side event I'm doing the following: e.Cell.Attributes.Add("oncontextmenu", string.Format("OnCellContextMenu({0}, '{1}', true, true)", e.VisibleIndex, e.DataColumn.FieldName));